# Doesn't work scorecards when it create in Business Central?

Tags: java, object, drools, jbpm, pmml

[image]

I think you have an error during auto-generation cod Scorecards in Business Central.

[image]

```
08:26:42,584 INFO  [org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.DataSourceManagementBootstrap] (pool-25-thread-1) Initialize deployments task finished successfully.
08:27:18,819 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 1) Creating output structures!
08:27:24,068 ERROR [org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl] (EJB default - 1) Error creating container 'dbtd_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' for module 'by.pstlabs:dbtd:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot mix rules with and without unit
        at org.drools.core.ruleunit.RuleUnitDescriptionRegistry$State.merge(RuleUnitDescriptionRegistry.java:88)
        at org.drools.core.ruleunit.RuleUnitDescriptionRegistry.add(RuleUnitDescriptionRegistry.java:53)
        at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.internalAddPackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:944)
        at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.lambda$addPackages$2(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:728)
        at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.enqueueModification(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:745)
        at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.addPackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:728)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.createKieBase(AbstractKieModule.java:227)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.createKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:407)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:375)
        at org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension.createContainer(DroolsKieServerExtension.java:98)
        at org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl.createContainer(KieServerImpl.java:293)
        at org.kie.server.services.impl.ContainerManager.installContainersSync(ContainerManager.java:44)
        at org.kie.server.services.impl.ContainerManager.installContainers(ContainerManager.java:33)
        at org.kie.server.jms.ContainerManagerEJB.installContainers(ContainerManagerEJB.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:103)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
        at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:82)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$2$2.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:152)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

08:27:24,086 INFO  [org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl] (EJB default - 1) KieServer sample-server is ready to receive requests
08:27:24,092 INFO  [org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorImpl] (EJB default - 1) Starting jBPM Executor Component ...
         - Thread Pool Size: 1
         - Retries per Request: 3
         - Load from storage interval: 0 SECONDS (if less or equal 0 only initial sync with storage)

08:27:24,101 INFO  [org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorImpl] (EJB default - 1) Executor JMS based support successfully activated on queue ActiveMQQueue[jms.queue.KIE.SERVER.EXECUTOR]
08:27:24,114 INFO  [org.jbpm.executor.impl.concurrent.LoadAndScheduleRequestsTask] (EE-ManagedThreadFactory-default-Thread-1) Load of jobs from storage started at Wed Apr 29 08:27:24 MSK 2020
08:27:24,130 INFO  [org.jbpm.executor.impl.concurrent.LoadAndScheduleRequestsTask] (EE-ManagedThreadFactory-default-Thread-1) Load of jobs from storage finished at Wed Apr 29 08:27:24 MSK 2020
```

Comment: Are you asking a questions or trying to report a bug? If you're asking a question, it's not clear what the question is, specifically. If you're trying to report a bug, this is the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have normal rules like DRL,spreedsheet,..etc in 'by.pstlabs:dbtd' project, am I correct ? If yes then you should move them to new projects. You can't have scoreCard and normal rules in same project. You can't have rule unit and rule in same kieBase

Comment: Yes, my project contains other RULES. I will try to transfer the SCORECARD to another project tomorrow and let you know about the result.